# Regex match number of backslashes but not more than x number

Tags: ruby, regex

Im trying to match double back slashes in a string, but only when there is 2 and not 3 so I can swap out the 2 for 3.

I know that `\\{2}` will match double back slash except it will also match the first 2 slashes when 3 are present.

For example in the string

```
{"files":{"windows": {"%windir%\\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\lmhosts.sam":{"ignore":{"id":32}},"%windir%\\System32\\\drivers\\etc":{"ignore":{"id":32}},"%windir%\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts":{"ignore":{"id":32}}}}}
```

There are multiple double slashes that I wish to match and replace, but there are also a few triple slashes which I wish to leave alone.

So, my question, how do match the double slash when it does not sit adjacent to another slash?

Heres a Regex101 link to toy with.
https://regex101.com/r/kWIscW/1

Also, doing this in Ruby.

Comment: Try this, **(?<!\\)\\{2}(?!\\)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first address backslashes in string literals,

- `"\\"` is one backslash
- `"\\\\"` are two backslashes
- `"\\\\\\"` are three backslashes

Why? Backslash is the escape sequence in string literals, eg `"\n"` is a linebreak, and hence a backslash must be escaped with a backslash to encode one backslash.

Now, try this

```
string = "\\\\aaa\\\\bbb\\\\\\ccc"
string.gsub(/\\+/) { |match| match.size == 2 ? '/' : match  } 
# => "/aaa/bbb\\\\\\ccc"
```

How does this work?

- `/\\+/` matches any sequence of backslashes
- `match.size == 2` filters those that have length 2
- And then we just replace those

Comment: Sorry doesnt seem to work for me, given 
string = "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\\Something",  this appears to modify the triple back slash down to 2

Comment: Be careful with strings, "\\" is only a single backslash, "\\\\" are two backslashes.

Comment: `"\\\\"` are two backslashes.

Comment: Cheyne. akuhn's code works fine for your stated question. Your example string contains only single backslash characters (`"\\"`), in some cases  followed by an escaped character (`"\\\S"`).

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
\b\\{2}\b
```

To define that you `\\` are the only one characters evaluated

Another possibility to is looking behind and look ahead, however, not sure your regex engine supports it:

```
(?<=[^\\])\\{2}(?=[^\\])
```

Comment: Damn, Casimir is correct.  If the string looks like \\Some\\Thing  it will miss the first set.  Otherwise it worked,  anyway around that?

Comment: This looks to do the trick , I can't see to get it working in Ruby though.  It does match what I need it to

Comment: The lookahead does not work at the begin and end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

```
r = /
    (?<!\\)  # do not match a backslash, negative lookbehind
    \\\\     # match two backslashes
    (?!\\)   # do not match a backslash, negative lookahead
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = "\\\\\ are two backslashes and here are three \\\\\\ of 'em"
puts str  
  # \\ are two backslashes and here are three \\\ of 'em
str.scan(r)
  #=> ["\\\\"]
```

Note that `s = "\\\\\ "` is two backslashes followed by an escaped space.

```
s.size
  #=> 3
s[0].ord
  #=> 92
92.chr
  #=> "\\"
s[1].ord
  #=> 92 
s[2].ord
  #=> 32
```